# Spark pass string condition and return column type

Tags: string, apache-spark, filter

I have a function, myFilter that I want to do this:

If the mode parameter is 'daily', then filter the data frame by date using the parameters 'dt' and dB'. This works.

If the mode parameter is 'custom', then filter by a valid condition passed as a String to the function like this:

val filcond = "col(\"custId\")===\"1\""

myFilter(mode, filcond)

Since the function returns a Column type, I think I need to convert the string to Column. But I have yet to find a way to do that. Any ideas how to do this?

```
  def myFilter(mode: String, filcond : String): Column = {

    val filterCondition: Column =
      if (mode == "daily") {
        $"update_date" >= date_sub(to_date(date_format(lit(dt), "yyyy-MM-dd")), dB) and $"update_date" <= to_date(date_format(lit(dt), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
      } else if (mode == "custom") {
        //col("custId")==="1"     //I want it to return this condition, but pass it in as a param to this function
        filcond      // this does not work since it is a String
      }
    return filterCondition
  }

  val myDf = ss.read
    .parquet("/data")
    .select (
      $"Id",
      $"Url",
      $"Type",
      $"custId",
      to_date($"updateTimestamp","yyyy-MM-dd").as("update_date")
    )
    .filter( myFilter(mode,filcond) )
```

Comment: Have you tried using `lit(filcond)` or `expr(filcond)`?

Comment: No I had not tried those. I tried lit(filcond) and I got this error: filter expression ''col("custId")==="1"'' of type string is not a boolean.   I also tried expr(filcond). With that I get this error: extraneous input '=' expecting...(then a whole long list of SQL keywords). Using expr seems like what I should be using, but I don't understand what it doesn't like about the value of filcond

Comment: `expr` expects a sql expression. Are you able to change the value inside `filcond` from `"col(\"custId\")===\"1\""` to `custId = 1` ?

Comment: OK that makes sense and worked. Thanks much!